# Why my app included another project Activity within activity, and How to remove it to have my activity old code

Tags: java, android

I developed a project two months ago called SociApp...After completion, I started a new project that includes Activity called DrinkActivity... Now the problem is that when I opened my old SociApp project it includes the DrinkActivity of my new Project within Activity called FindFriendActivity of SociApp and FindFriendActivity code is not showing anywhere.

The Activity in new Project:

[That activity is appeard within activity FindFriendActivity in SociApp click to see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JryH.jpg)

All the Drink Activity Code:

```
   package com.hfad.starbuzz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class DrinkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String EXTRA_DRINKNO = "drinkNo";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink);

        int drinkNo = (Integer) getIntent().getExtras().get(EXTRA_DRINKNO);
        Drink drink = Drink.drinks[drinkNo];

     try {

         SQLiteOpenHelper starBuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarBuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
         SQLiteDatabase db = starBuzzDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
         Cursor cursor = db.query("DRINK",
                  new String[]{"NAME", "DESCRIPTION", "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID"},
                  "_id = ?",
                   new String[]{Integer.toString(drinkNo)},
                  null, null, null);

         if (cursor.moveToFirst())
         {
             String nameText = cursor.getString(0);
             String descriptionText = cursor.getString(1);
             int photoId = cursor.getInt(2);

             TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
             TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
             ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);

             name.setText(nameText);
             description.setText(descriptionText);
             photo.setImageResource(photoId);
             photo.setContentDescription(nameText);
         }
         cursor.close();
         db.close();

     } catch (SQLiteException e)
     {
         Toast.makeText(this, "Database not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

        ImageView photo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photo);
        photo.setImageResource(drink.getImageResource());
        photo.setContentDescription(drink.getDescription());

        TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        name.setText(drink.getName());

        TextView description = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
        description.setText(drink.getDescription());
    }
}
```

I don't know why this happened, both have different package name different project but how this activity got here in SociApp...

and that's how my SociApp FindFriendActivity looks like:

[Click to see SociApp FindFriendActivity pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqy9Z.jpg)

Now all I want to remove the DrinkActivity and have my FindFriendActivity code back...
It gives an error... I don't understand.

I don't know how this DrinkActivity got into my old project and why... Please any help will be appreciated sorry for weak english. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post all the relevant code here in the post please?

Comment: why not sir a minute please

Comment: I don't know how an activity from the other project gets into another one please help...

Comment: Can you post the code for the `FindFriendActivity`? We need *all* the code related to the issue; otherwise, it's impossible to help.

Comment: That code is missing now sir, Whenever I click on FindFriendActivity it opens DrinkActivity and it's code

Comment: Sir please click on the links to see pictures I added. so that you can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you somehow replaced the `FindFriendActivity` code with the `DrinkActivity` code. Essentially what is happening is you have a class called `DrinkActivity` with a file name of `FindFriendActvity`. If you want to fix this, you need to replace the `DrinkActivity` code within `FindFriendActivity` code:

```
public class FindFriendActivity{
   //Your FindFriendActivity code would go here, whatever it was. 
}
```